# lombok call child class function for default builder

Tags: java, builder, lombok

I have 2 classes, where parent needs some property from child class while building. Is there a way to support this using lombok builders?

**Parent.java**

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent {
    @Builder.Default
    private String requestType = getRequestTypeFromSubclass();
    abstract String getRequestTypeFromSubclass();
}
```

**Child.java**

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

import java.util.List;

@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    String getRequestTypeFromSubclass() {
        return "Child1";
    }
}
```

The above fails in compilation with message

> error: non-static method getRequestType() cannot be referenced from a
>   static context @SuperBuilder

Comment: This is a problem falling all the way down to the question, of whether there should be `abstract static` methods in Java. I believe cases like this justify the concept, but the general premise of Java still seems to be 'polymorphism is a characteristic of object derivation, not class derivation'. (Not an answer yet, but I will check).

Comment: The above is not used on day to day basis, one of the use case is while doing jackson serialization. subclass is selected based on requestType key.

Answer (score 1):

As [suggested in Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-default-value) use `toBuilder=true` and remove `@Builder.Default`

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Getter
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder=true)
public abstract class Parent {

    private String requestType = getRequestType();
    abstract String getRequestType();
}
```

> With this, we can get rid of the double initialization

Change calling builder using `toBuilder`, Child:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    String getRequestType() {
        return "Child1";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child = Child.builder().build();
        System.out.println(child.getRequestType());
    }
}
```

Comment: @TreffnonX what's `defineRequestType()` ? Did you remove `@Builder.Default`?

Comment: I missed to remove the @Builder.Default over defineRequestType. That said, the code now fails at runtime. A test case of `@Test
 public void test_lombokBuilderPolymorphism() {
  Child child1 = Child.builder().build();
  assertEquals("child1", child1.getRequestType());
 }` fails at assertion: `expected: <child1> but was:<null>`

Comment: Change to `new Child().toBuilder().build()`

Comment: Hmm... this line does not compile for me at all. I guess I am doing something wrong. I start to get the concept. However I somehow feel, that maybe OP would be better helped using an init method... Also, I have to write: `Child child1 = new Child(Child.builder()).toBuilder().build();` for it to even compile. But it will yield the same result at runtime.

Comment: yes, this is not working for me. There is not .toBuilder(). @user7294900 can you please post both parent and child?

Comment: @bestwishes added child and parent

Comment: aah, toBuilder=true is not doing anything,  we have just overridden getRequestType(). if we change abstract method from getRequestType() to getRequestType2(), it will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

`Builder.Default` is defined in static scope and expression might not able to resolve the abstract method implementation.

Probably you want to try this instead:

```
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class Parent {

    private String reqType;
    abstract String getRequestType();

    public String getReqType() {
        return Objects.isNull(reqType) ? getRequestType() : reqType;
    }
}
```

Override the property method with different method name from actual attribute getter method and should resolve the issue.

Try with:

```
Parent parent = Child.builder().build();
```

Answer (score 0):

While lombok is a great tool for many things, in this very instance, you might want to avoid usign the builder pattern. The effect you desire (accessing a child's method at parent-initialization time is possible inside of standard POJO constructors.
The following works for me:

```java
@Getter
public abstract class Parent {
    private String requestType = defineRequestType();

    protected abstract String defineRequestType();
}
```

```java
@Getter
public class Child extends Parent {
    protected String defineRequestType() {
        return "child1";
    }
}
```

and the following test case:

```java
@Test
public void test_lombokBuilderPolymorphism() {
    Child child1 = new Child();
    assertEquals("child1", child1.getRequestType());
}
```

So unless you definitely require the builder pattern for some other reasons, the default POJO's capabilities seem to be enough here.

On a side note: You should name the defining method other than `get...` so it does not collide with the generated getter (`getRequestType`).